# What is the best query to get the current records in an archive table (SQL Server 2005/2008)

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008

## Example

There is an application that measures temperature in each town of the world. Each measurement is taken every 5 minutes and written in to the Measurement table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Measurement](
    [MeasurementID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Town] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Temp] [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Measurement] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [MeasurementID] ASC
)) ON [PRIMARY]
```

## Question

What is the most efficient query to get a list of the towns and their current temperature?

Assume there are 100k towns and 10 million records

*NOTE: I have added a couple of possible answers, but there are probably other options.*

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple that should work:

SELECT
    m1.Town, m1.Temp
FROM
    Measurement AS m1
LEFT JOIN
    Measurement AS m2
ON
    m1.Town = m2.Town
    AND m1.Date < m2.Date
WHERE
    m2.MeasurementID IS NULL
ORDER BY m1.Town

---

You'll need an index on Town and Date.

This technique is especially useful for early versions of MySQL, which couldn't handle the more obvious

SELECT Town, Temp
FROM Measurement AS m1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM Measurement
WHERE Town = m1.Town
AND Date > m1.date
)
ORDER BY Town

Comment: Interesting approach.  Do you know if it is more/less expensive that joining to a subquery that grabs the max date for each town?

Comment: I generally choose my query design by testing alternatives, and the NULL test always seems as fast as any. Then NOT EXISTS. Aggregate functions (like MAX) can sometimes give the query optimizer an excuse for reading multiple records which in this case aren't needed (with good indexing).

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from
(
    select distinct *, --Keyword,Total,CreatedOn,EngineInstanceID,
    Rank() over (PARTITION by Town order by Date DESC) as DateOrder
    from Measurement
    where Town is not null
) CurrentMeasurement
where DateOrder = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Good to see so many ways to skin this cat.  Here's one using a CTE (you can also nest the query for more ANSI-ism, but I find CTEs great to avoid a lot of indenting and declaring things up front makes it pretty readable up top and down below):

```
WITH LastMeasurements AS (
    SELECT [Town], MAX([Date]) AS LastMeasurementDate
    FROM [Measurement]
    GROUP BY [Town]
)
SELECT [Measurement].Town, [Measurement].[Date], [Measurement].Temp
FROM [Measurement]
INNER JOIN LastMeasurements
    ON [Measurement].[Town] = LastMeasurements.[Town]
    AND [Measurement].[Date] = LastMeasurements.LastMeasurementDate
```

What I like about the explicit seeking back technique is that it easily gives you access to all the information in the top row selected for the group and is very flexible in changing the grouping and low on repeating yourself.

The optimizer tends to perform these pretty quickly on SQL Server - like most solutions, if you have an index on Town, Date, Temp this will be covering and will run super fast.  Even if it's just on Town, Date, the bulk of the work in the `GROUP BY` can be done super fast anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.*
from Measurement s
where exists ( 
   select 1
   from Measurement s1
   where s.Town = s1.Town
   group by s1.Town
   having max( s1.Date )= s.Date)
   order by s.Town
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.town, m.temperature, m.date
from Measurement m
where m.date = (select max(m2.date) from Measurement m2 where m2.town = m.town)
order by 1
```

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis.

Comment: Not - I didn't see the scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Do you possibly have a table with a distinct list of Towns? Given that you have about 1000 measurements per town, a windowing function solution (such as row_number(), rank() etc.) may not perform as well as a normal aggregate or this APPLY version:

```
SELECT
   M.*
FROM
   Towns T
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 * -- add 'WITH TIES' to the 'TOP 1' if you have/want ties on date.
      FROM Measurement M
      WHERE T.Town = M.Town
      ORDER BY M.Date DESC
   ) M
```

If there is no list of towns, you can try this, though I don't know how it would stack up against the plain vanilla aggregate + lookup:

```
SELECT
   M.*
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT Town FROM Towns) T
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM Measurement M
      WHERE T.Town = M.Town
      ORDER BY M.Date DESC
   ) M
```

The performance of these queries will absolutely depend on indexes. You need one on [Town] at the bare minimum and [Town, Date] instead would be best. If other tables use the MeasurementID but you rarely access the Measurement table with MeasurementID, then drop the clustered index, make MeasurementID a nonclustered PK, and add a (nonunique) clustered index on Town, Date. If you don't have other tables using MeasurementID then drop that column completely--in that case it is a useless synthetic/artificial key bloating your table for no reason.

These recommended changes in indexes would help all of the queries in the answers here using aggregates or APPLY. Not sure about their affect on the windowing functions, it depends on how the optimizer works out the execution plans (if it's smart enough to realize it only needs to access the max date and not touch all the other rows then the same index will boost it incredibly, though I doubt the optimizer can do this).

Also, to increase performance I would suggest a Town table for sure, with TownID instead of putting the entire town in place. What if the name of the town changes? Switching from 15 or so bytes average for each name to only 4 bytes for an int TownID would help the speed. (Though testing is in order to prove this for sure).